# Date Range Matching Function pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, for-loop, date-range

I have a dataframe called `df1` that looks like this:

```
  Loc    Start      End 
  CA     2013-11-08 2014-04-14
  CO     2014-04-14 2014-04-16
  CA     2014-04-16 2014-04-18
  CO     2014-04-18 2014-04-23
```

And I have another dataframe called `df2` that looks like this:

```
Date       Loc Flag
2014-04-14  CO   0
2014-04-14  CO   0
2014-04-14  CO   0
2014-04-15  CO   0
2014-04-15  CO   0
2014-04-16  CO   0
2014-04-16  CO   0
2014-04-16  VA   0
2014-04-16  CA   0
```

I want to build a function such that for each `Start` and `End` period in `df1`, the function checks whether the rows in `df2` that fall in that date range match locations, i.e. do the `loc`'s match. Where they do not match, I want the `Flag` to be marked with a 1. Here is the code I tried:

```
for i in range(len(df1)):
    for j in range(len(df2)):
        if df2['Date'][j] <= df1['End Date'][i] and \
        df2['Date'][j] >= df1['Start Date'][i]: 
            if df2['Loc'][j] != df1['Loc'][i]:
                df2['flag'][j] = 1
```

My code puts 1's where the locations actually match. I think it is because of the overlapping `Start` and `End` dates. Any tips on how I can go about correcting this? Thank you

Comment: Is this a duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54582155/1240268

Comment: Please indicate your expected output for Flags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add date columns between 2 dates in Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54581325/add-date-columns-between-2-dates-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much more simple solution is to use merge_asof.  This is similar to a left-join except that we match on nearest key rather than equal keys. Here is more: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html

```
df1['interval'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['start_date'])
df2['interval'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])

df1.sort_values(by=['interval'])
df2.sort_values(by=['interval'])

df3 = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, on='interval', by='Loc')
```

Comment: Thank you, i never knew you could merge on nearest keys! Now I can just put a 1 in my `flag` column wherever  there are nan's.